# rxjs use async/await in map Rx.Observable.range(1, 5).map

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, async-await, rxjs

I want get a list from rxjs using async/await. What should I do?

```
function getData(num){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve(num + 1)
    })
}

async function create(){
    var list = await Rx.Observable.range(1, 5).map(async (num)=>{
        const data = await getData(num)
        return  data
    }).toArray().toPromise()

    return list
}


Rx.Observable.fromPromise(create()).subscribe(list=>{
    console.log(list)
}, err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

I get

```
[ Promise { 2 },
  Promise { 3 },
  Promise { 4 },
  Promise { 5 },
  Promise { 6 } ]
```

I want get data like this

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I think you want `Promise.all(…)` instead of `….toPromise()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a slightly old question. You might have got the answer already,  but I thought it's a nice challenge, which turned out to be a surprisingly simple one too!

**Just switch from `map()` to `concatMap()`.**

And you won't even need the `async` / `await` bit inside the mapping function. Although keeping or removing it doesn't seem to change anything for me.

So, the relevant bit can be simplified to:

```
async function create() {
  var list = await Rx.Observable.range(1, 5)
    .concatMap(num => getData(num))
    .toArray().toPromise();

  return list;
}
```

And again, you can keep it exactly as you had it in the question, and just change `map` to `concatMap`. I just wanted to see how far this can go

[Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/Meligy/pen/BzLdMQ?editors=0011)

Check the console at the bottom of the page for the results.

Comment: Can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952794/preserving-state-of-checkboxes-generated-by-rxjs

Comment: `flatMap` doesn't keep order, see this failing example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoaWgx?editors=0011

Comment: @Akuukis do you know why that is?

Comment: @jayarjo To retain order use `concatMap()`
https://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Comment: FYI `flatMap` was renamed to `mergeMap` and marked as deprecated. Source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap

Comment: `toPromise` is deprecated, and will be removed in rxjs8

Comment: You might also consider using `switchMap` in the case your async function returns a one-time observable (ex a Promise).